# Can't get phone number from pdu because (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus") is null

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, report, message

I'm making an app to send 10 SMS in a row but I need a report for every SMS I   send.I found some working solutions on that but it only shows Toast delivered. So I decide that in first will be good to have the number from which came the report.  I found some solutions on the internet with

```
(Object[]) bundle.get("pdus")
```

but it crashes every time. In debug, I've seen that the Object[] is null but I found some other data so I tried to get this.

```
Object[]) bundle.get("pdu")
```

That works and I tried to make SmsMessage object from pdu.
But when I tried to get the originatingAddress it crashes again.
Then in debug, I found that the originatingAddress is null, mostly everything was null except ServiceCenterAddress. In debug I found RecipientAddress and when I looked inside there was the number from which came the report! But SmsMessage doesn't have a method to get the recipient address. So I ask what I'm doing wrong?
Here is code of my sendSMS method and DeliverReceiver class.

```
public boolean sendSMS(String id, String num, String msg) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, msg, sentPI, deliveredPI);


    Log.e("Message Sent", num + "  " + msg + "  " + id);

    return true;
}
```

DeliverReceiver

```
public class DeliverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null){
            final Object ob = (Object) bundle.get("pdu");

            SmsMessage current = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])ob);
            String num = current.getOriginatingAddress();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Deliver Reciever",e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can attach extras to the `Intent` used to create delivery `PendingIntent` to determine which you're getting in the Receiver. For example, to attach the phone number: `new Intent(DELIVERED).putExtra("phone_number", num)`. In the Receiver, retrieve that with `String num = intent.getStringExtra("phone_number");`. Also, to check delivery success/failure, you want to look at the return from [`getStatus()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getStatus()) called on that `SmsMessage`. If it's zero, it's a success.

Comment: I tried that before. So I started with to messages. First num - 49638 Sec. num - 72186 (Example). But for both messages it shows num 49638.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. I forgot to mention that you'll need to ensure a new `PendingIntent` is created for each message. The simplest way to do that is to pass a unique `int` for each as the second parameter in `getBroadcast()`.

Comment: And then in Receiver. How can i get it ?

Comment: Nothing changes on that end: `String num = intent.getStringExtra("phone_number");`.